# Locally rename a BibTeX entry name

Tags: bibtex, languages

I'm writing a project in Spanish and I've noticed that when using the `@MASTERTHESIS` entry for BibTeX the output is typeset as "Master's thesis"; I'd like it to be "Tesis de Maestría", which is the proper name in Spanish.

I tried using the `babelbib` package but when typesetting I get "Tesis de Licenciatura" which is not what I want, so basically I need the same if I use this package, namely:

**Is there a way to change the typeset name of the entry type for just one article/book without having to edit the `.bst` file?**

Please help. Thank you!

Comment: have you had a look into babelbib? This is what it does: `\def\btxmastthesis##1{\protect\foreignlanguage{#1}{Tesis de Licenciatura}}%`  (You probably would have to redefine the whole bibsspanish command, but you get the gist)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The field `type` is just for this.  Put in your entry

```
type = {Tesis de Maestría},
```